# How to insert a row into FlexiDB Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server

How do you insert a new object or row into a collection for FlexiDB? I am using the DEV 1.0.0 release and using the FlexiDB Client to do some test queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Easy!

```
$.collection('yourcollectionname').insert({name: "Test"});
```

Take a look at the project on GitHub.

[FlexiDB Server](https://github.com/mrbenosborne/Flexi-DB)

[FlexiDB Client](https://github.com/mrbenosborne/FlexiDB-Client)